# Convert Date to Hours only using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, time

I would to add a certain amount of hours to a date time using PHP.
 I am interested to show the result only using hour format.

For example, I add 8 hours to a date time as follow:

```
$result= date("H:i", strtotime('18:00') + 8*3600);
```

But I got as result value **01:00**, but I would get 26 as result..

Can you help me please, I could not find the solution :(

Thank you all

Comment: 26:00 is not a time, you should be getting 02:00 because 24:01 is actually 0:01 25:00 => 1:00. Don't know how you're getting 1:00... but if you want a number that isn't time just get the time as a number (not a date) and add to it.

Answer (score 2):

It's easier with [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php):

```
$date = new DateTime('18:00:00');
$date->modify('+8 hours');
echo $date->format('H:i');
```

**Edit:** Maybe I don't understand the question then. If you want to get `26`, then you can use something like:

```
$date = new DateTime('18:00:00');
echo $date->format('H') + 8;
```

Comment: You're doing the same thing he is. that will echo 02:00

Comment: @Bryan I thought OP gets `26` and that's the problem. Don't exactly understand the question then. Added an other example though.

Comment: Yeah I don't know what he wants either, your second example is what I think he is after.

Comment: Tank you Gergo Erdosi, for suggestino!! With this I got 26 hour as I wish. But if I sum 8 hour to a date format, for example '18:30:00', how could I obtain 26:30 as result? Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP dates math. `strtotime()` returns a unix timestamp, which is number of seconds since the epoch, midnight January 1,1970.

`date()` takes those timestamps and formats them into whatever representation you want. But `'H'` is **NOT** "hours since time zero". it's "hours of the day". If you have a timestamp that represents Jul 8/2014 12 noon, then `H` is going to be 12, because it's noon. It's not going to be 50 bajillion hours since Jan 1/1970.

e.g.

```
Jul 8/2014 11pm  + 3 hours = Jul 9/2014 2am. 
date('H' of Jul 9/2014)  = 2, not "14"
```

Comment: I simply would to add an amount of hour to datetime and I would amount of hour as result....for example if I sum 10 hours to 08:30 I would get 18:30 as result. My problem is that if I sum 8 hours to datetime '18:00:00' I get '02:00' as result, but I would get '26:00' as result.

Comment: exactly. because 6pm + 8hours = 2am. you're trying to use date() in a way it's never been intended to use. it's NOT for calculating date/time intervals. it's intended to take a timestamp and format it into various values that represent that time. date('H') is the current hour-of-the-day, not "hours since some arbitrary point in time"